# React Native Android WebView How to disable horizontal scroll?

Tags: android, css, react-native, webview

I have a problem with webview and scrolling. I want to disable all scrolling. I used `scrollEnabled`, for IOS it works fine. But for android no property like this exists. I tried a lot of scripts but nothing works.

At first look everything seems ok but if user swipes to right side then the text/div moves outside of screen.

[image: how it looks like when it is ok]

and this is what happened

[image: how it looks like when user will swipe to side]

this is my webview:

```
<WebView
  bounces={false}
  ref={(element) => { this.webViewRef = element; }}
  javaScriptEnabled
  scalesPageToFit={false}
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
  style={{
    height: this.state.webViewHeight,
  }}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  source={{
    html: `
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>${injectedStyle(platformStyles.fontSizes.base || 16, webViewWidth)}</head>
            <body>
              <div id="baseDiv" class="ex1">${content}</div>
              ${injectedJS}
            </body>
          </html>
    `,
    baseUrl: 'http://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
  }}
  onNavigationStateChange={this._processNavigationStateChange}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
/>
```

and i tried to add a style like this ( `overflow: 'hidden'` but its doesn't work):

```
    const injectedStyle = (fontSize, widhtPlatform) => `<style type="text/css">
    ...
    body {
            display: flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: orange;
    ...
        }
    div.ex1 {
      overflow: hidden;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid blue;
    ...
    }
    </style>`;
```

and JS to disable scroll:

```
const injectedJS = `
  <script>
    var scrollEventHandler = function()
      {
        window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset)
      }
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEventHandler, false);
    document.getElementById('scrollbar').style.display = 'block';
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

  </script>
`;
```

We use RN:

`react-native-cli: 2.0.1`

`react-native: 0.53.3`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Android change `scalesPageToFit={false}` into `scalesPageToFit={true}`. It will work.

```
// ....
const scalesPageToFit = Platform.OS === 'android';

// .... 
return 
    <WebView
      scalesPageToFit={scalesPageToFit}
      bounces={false}
      scrollEnabled={false}
// ....
```

Update: for recent versions of rn-webview depending on the html content you might need to use also some extra css to target the content that has problems:

`max-width: 100%;`

`overflow-x: hidden`;

and/or `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}`

Comment: This does not work in android. I tried the code but the page scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i react-native-render-html@foundry 

import HTML from 'react-native-render-html'

 <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      <HTML 
       contentWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
       onLinkPress={(e,href)=>onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e,href)}
        html={'<p>your html</p>' }
        tagsStyles={ { p: { textAlign: 'center', fontStyle: 'normal', color: 'black' 
        ,fontFamily:'Mukta-Regular',fontWeight:'100'} }} />
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to disable the scrollbar -

For Horizontal scrollbar -
`showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}`

For Vertical scrollbar -
`showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}`

Comment: you will only hide the scroll bar. not what the question asks.

Comment: This worked perfectly!, It is hiding scroll bars.